# A basis of this vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am looking for a basis of the set of solutions of $u_{n+2}=u_{n+1}+u_{n}$... Is there some easy basis?  I know that all solutions are determined by $u_0, u_1$ but I don't know how to find a basis.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the solutions of $u_0=0, u_1=1$  and $u_0=1, u_1=0$ as base

Comment: Very good answer! The problem-poser may be expecting the functions $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$ and  $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$,

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes I did think that it was the right answer... isn't it?

Comment: @Jaxon, I found $u_n=n-1$ for all $n\geq1$ and $u_{0}=1$ (and $u_{1}=0$...). For $u_{0}=0$ and $u_{1}=1$ I found $u_n=n-1$ for all $n\geq2$. Then?

Comment: The answer I gave is a correct answer. The answer given by Lord_Gestalter is another correct answer. There are infinitely many correct answers.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, okay... thus a basis is $Span\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{2}, \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^{2}\right)$ ?

Comment: The space is a space of functions from the set $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ to the reals, or if you prefer it is a space whose elements are infinite sequences. The two sequences that I mentioned in the comment above are a two-element basis for our space. Your suggested basis is not right, it is not linearly independent, contains only constant sequences, which do not (except for the $0$-sequence) satisfy the recurrence.